# itext7 - Cannot get trial license to load for itext 7 .2.0

Tags: itext, itext7

I trying explore pdfoffice functionality of itext 7. have obtained 30 day trial license. when call licensekey.loadlicensefile(path-to-key-file), returns without errors,following error:

licensekeyexception license file not loaded.

Comment: Have you contacted itext support?

Comment: This is not a question for SO since we do not answer license related questions regarding a commercial product.  You need to contact iText support: https://itextpdf.com/en/support